# libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, bundler, passenger

I have a RoR (4.1) app that I'm trying to deploy, using Passenger & Nginx. I'm trying to avoid running "bundle install" on the web server. I ran "bundle install --deployment" on my build server, zipped up the whole folder and shipped it to the web server. But now I'm getting this error:

`libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /var/www/foo_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)`

The file does exist, and has read & execute permissions for all users (and rwx for the user I think passenger is running as). Any ideas what I'm missing?

I've had no end of problems getting this working, should I just give in and bundle on the target machine?